# JaCoCo reporting 0% code coverage

Tags: android, junit, jacoco

I am trying to setup test coverage with jacoco but I've been unsuccessful so far.

In my build.gradle I have added:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

(...)

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }

(...)

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test<MyFlavor>DebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = []
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes:
            ['**/*.exec' , '**/*.ec'])
}
```

Then I run the JaCoCo test report with the following code:

```
./gradlew clean create<MyFlavor>DebugCoverageReport jacocoTestReport
```

I see that the unit tests are run successfully, but when I open the test report, located in:

```
<project>/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html
```

the report seems to be empty, as coverage is reported as N/A and not even the project packages are displayed.

Moreover, if I try to open the coverage file at

```
<project>/build/jacoco/test<MyFlavor>DebugUnitTest.exec
```

using Android Studio, all classes report 0.0% coverage.

I am using gradle 3.0.1

What am I doing wrong? 
Does this have something to do with the usage of flavors?

Comment: Please show the gradle build output (limited to Jacoco details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to find a solution to this problem.

It seems that, as we use gradle flavors, we had to add the flavor in the `classDirectories` line.

Here is our current task, with that change:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test<MyFlavor>DebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = []
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/<MyFlavor>/", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes:
            ['**/*.exec' , '**/*.ec'])
}
```

Comment: from where one is having this file path "test<MyFlavor>DebugUnitTest")..how can i setup this in my gradle folder

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with UnitTests and JaCoCo. I solved my problem by using a different [plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin).

In your root `build.gradle` add:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin:0.10.0'
    }
}
```

and apply the plugin in your module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.vanniktech.android.junit.jacoco'
```

After a sync you should have new gradle tasks:

```
jacocoTestReport<<BuildVariant>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that plugin, but it seems like it is not compatible with gradle 3.0.1 :(

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. We have the same gradle android plugin version... But we used version 0.10.0 of this plugin in our code.

Comment: Perfect!. This solution actually worked like a charm :)